# Chrome profile disabling ASP buttons

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, button, microsoft-edge

I've been working on our web application for 10+ years.

Everything has worked fine until recently, when all of a sudden, asp:buttons just stopped working.  LinkButtons are fine, but regular buttons are *completely* disabled.  They work fine on the other developers' computers but not mine.

I tried everything and was ready to move to Edge, when buttons stopped working on Edge as well.

I reinstalled Chrome and behold, it worked! Then I signed into my profile and it stopped.

When I go incognito, the asp:button works just fine.

Sign into my profile and they're disabled again.

I'm going crazy.  Cleared all the cookies.  No extensions are enabled.  It's like there's some security setting turning it all off.

It's only happening in development on localhost (a public https URL pointing to my computer).

Anyone else had this issue?

Comment: Are you talking about asp: button or <button> with a runat server? I use edge which is chrome based and it's ok - I've not seen a boatload of posts appear in the community, so clearly this is not a wide spread problem. Create a simple page and with a single button and thus post a reproducible example here so others can try.

Comment: The <asp:button>  

All the asp:buttons work on other PC's.  It works fine on my PC in incognito mode and when I'm not signed into the browser. 

Once I sign into Chrome or Edge, all the <asp:buttons> deactivate.

There's no code to show.  It works fine until I sign in.

I figured it was an XSS extension, but I've removed all them and reinstalled Chrome.  Same thing - it all dies when I log in.

Otherwise, it would be a coding issue... but it works incognito and on other dev's computers.  It's related to a Chrome setting or something to do with my profile.

LinkButtons work fine.

Comment: Chrome doesn't know about asp:Button. No browsers do. That's a server side concept, from the ASP.NET Web Forms framework. It just renders HTML and JavaScript. So if something is disabling them on the client side, you need to check what's going on there.

Comment: The asp:button renders to an input HTML field. It makes zero sense that a browser login (not website login) disables input buttons unless the act of logging in is running something on browser side. I don’t believe there’s anything wrong with the code or it would never work at all.

Comment: Does the issue happen in other non-chromium browsers? Does it work when you login profile with another account? Have you tried to clear all browser data in *edge://settings/clearBrowserData* and test again? Besides, you can open F12 devtools to check if there's any error in console and try to debug the code.

Comment: I've cleared all the cookies, reinstalled Chrome etc.  That's how I found out that it works when the browser isn't logged into Chrome.

Comment: Works in Prod, not development. Works on other Developer's computers, just not mine.  Works in Firefox.

It was working in Edge until recently - I imported some plugins, but they're all removed and disabled now.  Unfortunately, MS doesn't let you uninstall edge.

Comment: It also seems that adding UseSubmitBehavior="false" to the button makes it work.

If it's true, it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Well this was a funky issue... still is.

Using <asp:button usesubmitbehaviour="true"> renders to    This apparently submits the entire form using special browser code - whatever that means...

Using <asp:button usesubmitbehaviour="true"> renders to  (the type "submit" changes to "button")  It's supposed to fire off a postback using javascript but that doesn't always work either.

A LinkButton renders the   This works really well and there's only minor testing as it's pretty much a simple replace.

There's some reports around that there's a caching issue (javascript?) which "may" explain why it works incognito. Even with new reinstalls and clearing caches, it still doesn't work.

So haven't figured it out completely, but hopefully this will help someone in the future.